Applying for a Masters degree in ECE with a low average GPA & B.S. degree not in ECE
I'm a senior Math major, looking to apply for a MS in Electrical/Computer Engineering. However, my degree is in Math. I have taken some ECE courses in embedded system and microcontrollers, and the 100-200 lvl sequence for your average Computer Science degree, up to Data Structures and algorithms.
However, due to life circumstances, I had to only take the math degree. However, my GPA is sub-3.0. This is partly due to COVID and the tribulations of being an independent student, who was way below the poverty line for most of their college career. I also did - ironically enough - struggle with math starting out in college and my early grades, sadly, demonstrate that.
I do have a lot of research experience through REUs and National Labs, doing computational science/HPC development. I'm even a coauthor for some math papers.
But my GPA and my major worry me about the possibility of acceptance for a MSECE program.
Of course, someone may ask me why I even want to do a Masters in ECE. I'm particularly fascinated about applying computational category theory to resource-limited computational systems such as cubesats or edge IoT systems. Possibly could have applications in signals processing the same way topology [1] has been applied to signals processing.
What could I do right now to improve my chances to be accepted to a good MSECE program?
[1] Robinson, M. (n.d.). Topological Signal Processing. SpringerLink. https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-642-36104-3

Ask them.
A good institution will be receptive to someone asking “Is there any point in my applying for this course?” or even “Would this course be a suitable fit for me?”.
It is best to make it very clear that you are not trying to circumvent the application process. One way to do this is to ask to discuss what could make you a suitable candidate at some time in the future.
For example, one person I know who wanted to do an undergraduate course had the problem of being older than a school-leaver but too young to count as a mature student. She asked the college for advice as to what admissions route to follow and received excellent advice.
